# Angular2 or React for dynamically displaying data vs just jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, angular, reactjs

Being relatively new to web development, I am trying to understand the various technologies out there that enable the following types of behavior:

1. Displaying user specified data from a database without refreshing the page
2. Narrow down data displayed in a data table based on a text box (e.g., typing in "t" automatically narrows down to results that contain that, further typing "th" narrows it down further, "the" narrows it down further, etc.
3. Lastly auto-complete when typing

Not necessarily looking to SPAs.

I had been under the impression this was just accomplished with AJAX via jQuery. But now that I have been reading more about AngularJS, Angular2, and ReactJS, it sounds like these are used to accomplish the same thing and much more.

So I am wondering do these frameworks replace jQuery?

As far as industry trends, where does it seem to be heading? In favor of AngularJS, Angular2, or ReactJS?

Sounds like ReactJS is easier to learn and accomplishes the same thing so leaning towards learning it first. Reading some articles that suggested these frameworks should be implemented at the beginning of a project instead of going back and adding them. Figured it would be good to pick one up before I get much further.

Comment: Nobody decide that for you. I would suggest to try them. The experience you get with frameworks and real-world use of design patterns will undoubtedly improve your framework-less jQuery/vanilla JS dev habits. But it is likely that you will prefer a framework you've mastered in the majority of cases just because it keeps you from reinventing the wheel and does the job.

Comment: If you are only looking for data binding, Knockout JS is also a very good option http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I use React daily and couldn't recommend it enough - for something like what you are talking about, I would say just stick with jQuery.

This is because jQuery had everything you list as requirements (often already developed in terms of plugins).

Your requirements aren't revolutionary, so everything is going to be very "Google-able" with jQuery as well. Though the same will most likely be said for React/Angular, you are reducing complexity by keeping it simple for a relatively simple app.